# Django fastcgi hangs

Tags: django, fastcgi

I'm trying to run Django with fastcgi. With `runserver` I've already tested that the site works fine in production. When I run

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=9500
```

the daemon runs, but every call just hangs, like this:

```
pistacchio@amaterasu:~/sites/comesichiama$ python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.1 port=9500 
pistacchio@amaterasu:~/sites/comesichiama$ wget 127.0.0.1:9500
  --2012-02-18 22:55:37--  http://127.0.0.1:9500/
  Connecting to 127.0.0.1:9500... connected.
  HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

I don't know what is going on and I have no idea on how to debug an eventual error. Also

```
python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=9500 debug=true daemonize=false outlog=out.log errlog=err.log
```

Doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running FastCGI on port 9500 is not the same as running a webserver -- using wget won't work. I know this from bitter experience, having wasted an afternoon trying the same thing ;)

You need to configure a webserver, for example Apache or Nginx, to serve your site using FastCGI. See the Django [deployment docs for FastCGI](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) for help with this. You can then test wget on the port that the webserver is running on e.g. 80 or 8000.